# Pandas: Create array with group indices

Tags: group-by, pandas

I'm looking for an efficient, all-Pandas way of creating an array with group numbers (for every row in the original dataframe I want a number that tells me which group this row belongs to):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]})
groups = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])
group_names = sorted(groups.groups.keys())
group_indices = np.array(df.index)
for index, group in enumerate(group_names):
    group_indices[groups.indices[group]] = index
```

where

```
In : df 
Out]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  1
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  1    

In : groups.indices
Out:
{(1, 1): array([0, 2]),
 (1, 2): array([1]),
 (2, 1): array([3, 5]),
 (2, 2): array([4])}

In : group_indices
Out: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2])
```

My problem is that if `df` is around 20000x100 (64 bit floats) and I group by two of the columns, I get memory usage above 6 GB. Which is way more than I'd expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indicies are already embedded in the groupby object

```
In [52]: groups.grouper.levels
Out[52]: [Int64Index([1, 2], dtype=int64), Int64Index([1, 2], dtype=int64)]

In [53]: groups.grouper.labels
Out[53]: [array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])]

In [57]: l = groups.grouper.labels

In [58]: zip(*l)
Out[58]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]

In [18]: groups.grouper.group_info
Out[18]: (array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), 4)
```

Simple lookup operations as these are already computed on the grouping object

```
In [19]: groups.grouper.group_info[0]
Out[19]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2])
```

Comment: This also works quite nicely, and it certainly is cleaner though I think it's more magic since I have real trouble finding documentation on the group objects. I could also find the correct labels using `groups.grouper.result_index.tolist()`. Thanks!

Comment: you never explained why you are doing with the info, you normally would have no need for this as the groupby takes care of the bookkeeping in its operations. what are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks for mentioning `grouper`, as it is not documented! I finally found a solution to change rows in original dataframe while iterating over its grouped object, using `grouped.grouper.indices`. I had to use it because I have duplicate DateTime indices in the dataframe. Also the transformation is too complicated to fit a `grouped` then `apply` paradigm, it involves clustering and filling in multiple dataframes at once while going through each group.